# Finding the non-zero eigenvalue and eigenvector of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a non-zero column vector $a = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]^t$, find the
non-zero eigenvalue and eigenvector of the matrix $aa^t$.

And that matrix $aa^t$ is symmetric, and there is a formula $A= PDP^{-1}$, and in this case $P^t = P^{-1}$, so $A = PDP^t$. But then i still have no idea how to find the eigenvalue and eigenvector? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867888/eigen-value-and-eigen-vector-of-a-matrix) was asked a few minutes ago. Would it be from some ongoing exam?

Comment: no, it is a homework question

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- the column space of $aa^\top$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $a$. So a nonzero eigenvector must lie in this subspace.
- all other eigenvalues are zero. (To find corresponding eigenvectors, consider vectors orthogonal to $a$.)
- Once you find all the eigenvalues, create an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors. This will allow you to explicitly construct $A = PDP^\top$, where the columns of $P$ are the members of this basis, and the diagonal elements are the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: thank   you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very convenient formula for your problem. i.e
$$|\lambda I-A_{n\times m}B_{m\times n}|=\lambda^{n-m}|\lambda I-B_{m\times n}A_{n\times m}|$$
The eigenvector is the vector perpendicular to  $\vec a$, and since you notice  $aa^T=(aa^T)^T$ then you must know the  $aa^T$  is self-adjoint whose eigenvectors are perpendicular to each other then $\vec a$ itself must be the last eigenvector.

Comment: thank you !!!!!!!!